# Why use a special library for reading .env file

Tags: php, laravel

Please explain the reason why .env file is written in such a weird format. It could be a simple PHP/INI/JSON file that easily renderable/writable by built-in PHP functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is similar to what you would use to set up the environment on your system's shell, like Bash.  Whomever chose it for Laravel had the opinion that this is what they wanted to be compatible with.